# C# filter multiline double quoted string with Regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, string, quotes, multiline

I want to filter the following strings using Regular expression in C#.

```
+CUSD: 2,"Your account balance is BDT 00.00 valid till 02/05/14. Dial *789*1*1# to get daily General Health Tips,Charge Tk 1.73/SMS", 15

+CUSD: 1,"1 Call Block
2 Mobile Service
3 Infotainment
4 Recharge
5 Roaming
6 Internet
7 Product & Promotion
8 Account Info
9 GP STAR", 15
```

The first one is single line. Second one is multiline.

`Regex regex1 = new Regex("\\+CUSD: (\\d+),\"(.*?)\", (\\d+)\\r\\n", RegexOptions.Multiline);`

This Filter the first string but not the other.

What will be the common filter for both string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RegexOptions.SingleLine` instead.

From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> **Singleline** Specifies single-line mode. Changes the meaning of the dot
>   (.) so it matches every character (instead of every character except
>   \n).

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following Regex...

```
\+CUSD: (\d+),\"[\s\S]*?\", (\d+)
```

Good Luck!